# Change SHA-1 key used for Google Sign In

Tags: android, google-play

My app uses Google Sign In and this requires a package name and SHA-1 fingerprint in order to enable the Google Sign In for the app and get the json configuration file. Naively, since it was a work in progress, I used the SHA-1 from the debug keystore, rather than a production key. I can't seem to change the SHA-1 associated to the app and the Google Sign In service now.

What are my options here? One I've considered is changing the package name for the app, and regenerating the configuration file.

Comment: you can add multiple sha-1 in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change package name!

1. Go to cloud.google.com
2. Choose APIs and Services from the menu at the left
3. Choose credentials
4. Choose the OAuth 2.0 client id you want to change, eg "Android client 1"
5. Click on the thing that looks like a pencil to edit it
6. Edit the signing certificate, and click save

OR alternatively, at step 4 just add a new client id with the same package name but a different certificate if you want both debug and production to work.

Comment: This does not work. Trying to edit a SHA1 results in and error. Trying to delete the current credential and create a new one does not work and also results in  the same error. The error states that the package name is already in use.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge I do not think there is a way to change the value once you have put it in, so changing the package name and regenerating your configuration file is the safe and easy way to go. Let me know if that works out!

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot. This probably means I would have to delete the project in Google Cloud Console as well.

Comment: yeah it's kind of a hassle, when I was doing the same for my app I had to restart the whole process, wish Google fixed that in the future :/